# Developing a news feed of a sns with Firebase(NoSQL)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, social-networking, feed, nosql

I’m trying to develop an app which is a social network service with firebase. Everything is alright. But, I got stuck when I think about news feed feature. Sure, I can find the posts user by user. But it's not cool and inefficient. Or, there is another idea. Create news feed document for the user, and add someone's posts when user follows or someone writes a post. But it is also not that good.

How could I make news feed feature with Firebase(or NoSQL, whatever)? I really want to know how to make news feed with NoSQL.

Answer (score -2):

Actually Firebase blog explained about this on [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html).

```
{
  "timeline": {
    "user2": {
      "-K-zOrtjiCGe7tgRk8DG": {
        "text": "I love emojis!",
        "uid": "user1"
      }
    },
    "user3": {
      "-K-zOrtjiCGe7tgRk8DG": {
        "text": "I love emojis!",
        "uid": "user1"
      }
    }
  },
  "followers": {
    "user1": {
      "user2": true,
      "user3": true
    }
  }
}
```

It calls "Fan-out" process. And it's kind broad topic for NoSQL database environment.

Comment: This isn't actually the fan out process. That comes later in the article. This is just an example of data denormalization.

Comment: @lustig dude, I didn't mean to the structure example code means "Fan-out". I just referenced the data structure which is fanned out to show how OP should consider database design. and I think this can be sufficient answer since I added fully explained link and data denormalization is needed for "Fan-out" not the answer though.